# Highlight gridview cell if " " or null

Tags: c#, regex, gridview

Here's what I'm using:

```
if (Regex.Match(gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text, "^[\x20 ]").Success)
            {
                gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: Red");
                Save.Visible = false;
            }
```

But it only highlights nulls (string.Empty) and not blanks (" "). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text))
{
    gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: Red");
    Save.Visible = false;
}
```

would probably perform better.

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` will match any string that is null, empty, or just whitespace characters.  So if the `.Text` property really is a string with just a space it should match.  It loks to me like this is not the case.  If `.Text` is not of type `string` then maybe you need `.Text.ToString()`.

Comment: some cells returns nbsp. I think that's the problem

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but have you tried .Trim() on the Text value? It can remove line breaks though if the text explicitly includes "nbsp", you may need to do a .Replace("nbsp", "")

Comment: -1: This doesn't seem to work. The non-breaking space HTML entity isn't recognized as whitespace by the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method. (@PodMays: You pointed out yourself that this doesn't work, but you have accepted it anyway - would you please explain what you did to get it working?)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text))` ?

It will provide the same (correct) functionality

Comment: That won't match single spaces

Comment: @postman the edited version works for nulls, thanks. but not for the white spaces.

Comment: @Pod Mays trim `.Text.Trim()` but I'm pretty sure that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` will pick that up.

Answer (score 1):

Per Pod Mays and Mike Byers question regarding matching the HTML whitespace entity 'nbsp', you can use the [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) method to decode the html. This will convert the 'nbsp' html entity into a ' ' so it can be matched by [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text)))
{
    gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: Red");
    Save.Visible = false;
}
```

Note that decoding the text is important because the gridview will convert completely empty cells to cells with a space (`&nbsp;`) in them.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (Regex.Match(gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text, "^[\\s]?$").Success)
{
    gv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: Red");
    Save.Visible = false;
}
```